# Trying to get hover animations working on crossfire image grid script

Tags: jquery, css, animation, opacity

I have adapted the crossfire image grid script from this [website](http://webdesigncrowd.com/demo/Grid-Gallery-6.6.11/) to suit my purposes, and you can see the result [here](http://salliannputman.com/work.html).

For some reason the opacity transitions are not working correctly on each 'box' in the grid.  They work fine when I download the demo, but not with my amended CSS/script.  In the script I have only changed the dimensions of the boxes and the calculations for moving the indicators.  In the CSS I have changed the width of the boxes.

Can anyone tell why the opacity transitions aren't working correctly?

Here is the crossfire script:

```
(function($){   

    $(function(){

        var boxWidth = 10 + 200;
        var currentBox;
        var currentRow;
        var currentCol;

        var gridWidth = $('#container').width();
        var n = gridWidth / boxWidth;
        var numColumn = Math.floor(n);


        $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n)').addClass('lastBox');
        $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n + 1)').addClass('firstBox');

        $(window).resize(function() {

                    $('div.box').removeClass('lastBox').removeClass('firstBox');
                    var gridWidth = $('#container').width();
                    var n = gridWidth / boxWidth;
                    var numColumn = Math.floor(n);

                    $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n)').addClass('lastBox');
                    $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n + 1)').addClass('firstBox');

        });


        $('#container').hover(
                  function () {
                    $('#container .box').animate({opacity: '.25'}, {queue: false});
                 }, 
                  function () { 
                    $('#container .box').animate({opacity: '1'}, {queue: false});
                    $('#topIndicator-wrapper').animate({left: 0}, {queue: false});
                    $('#leftIndicator-wrapper').animate({top: 10}, {queue: false});
                    $('#leftIndicator-wrapper').css({position: 'absolute'});
                 }
        );      
        $('.box').hover(
                  function () {
                    $('div.box').removeClass('lastBox').removeClass('firstBox');
                    var gridWidth = $('#container').width();
                    var n = gridWidth / boxWidth;
                    var numColumn = Math.floor(n);

                    $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n)').addClass('lastBox');
                    $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n + 1)').addClass('firstBox');

                    currentBox = $(this).parent().children().index(this) + 1;
                    r = currentBox / numColumn;
                    currentRow = Math.ceil(r);
                    currentCol = currentBox - numColumn*(currentRow-1);

                    $('#topIndicator-wrapper').animate({left: 210*(currentCol-1)+50}, {queue: false});
                    $('#leftIndicator-wrapper').animate({top: 10+210*(currentRow-1)+50}, {queue: false});   
                    $('#leftIndicator-wrapper').css({position: 'relative'});            
                    $(this).prevUntil("div.lastBox").animate({opacity: '.5'}, {queue: false});
                    $(this).nextUntil("div.firstBox").animate({opacity: '.5'}, {queue: false});
                    $('div.box:nth-child(' + numColumn + 'n + ' + currentCol +')').animate({opacity: '.50'}, {queue: false});
                    $(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, {queue: false});
                 }, 
                  function () { 
                    $('.box').animate({opacity: '.25'}, {queue: false});
                 }
        );


    }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#container` was not set to clear the floated elements within it (staying a very small height at top of screen), so the `$('#container').hover` script was not activating. Adding `overflow: auto` to the css of `#container` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that sorted it nicely.